# Bilvavi Mishkan Evneh

Tags: sources-mekorot

Aside from the book series by Rabbi Itamar Schwartz, from where does the above quote come?  I have googled this statement; of course, I come upon Ex. 25:8 - "V'asu li mikdash," but I don't know how to find the above quote.  It usually takes me to Rabbi Schwartz' books and also to a longer quote, whose origin I would like to know.  This is the quote:

בלבבי משכן אבנה להדר כבודו, ובמשכן מזבח אשים לקרני הודו, ולנר תמיד אקח לי את אש העקידה, ולקרבן אקריב לו את נפשי, את נפשי היחידה.

In my heart will build a Mishkan/Tabernacle/

to glorify His honor//

In this Mishkan I shall [also] place an alter/

to acknowledge His splendor//

And [as for what fire I shall use] I will take to me the fire of the eternal light /

[which is] the fire of the Akeidah//

And as [for what] sacrifice will I bring/

I will offer my soul, my own unique and special soul//

Thank you for any help.  Shana Tova, Susanne

Comment: Here is the source. http://www.zemirotdatabase.org/view_song.php?id=15

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSVipK7HaEY

Answer (score 6):

The song was composed by R' Yitzchok Hutner (פחד יצחק), and is based on the words of the בעל החרדים (R' Elazar Azkari).

These are the words of the חרדים (in פרק לד part of a longer song based on the א"ב),

> בתוך לבי משכן אבנה לזיוו, קרבן תקריב לו נפשי היחידה

Comment: Yes, most people do not realise this was composed by Rav Hutner.

Comment: The words were composed by Rav Hutner with a different tune than the well known one. When Rav Hutner heard the tune that Shmuel Brazil composed to his words, he said this was the correct tune for them.  Hence the tune is by Rabbi Shmuel Brazil and the lyrics were penned by Rav Hutner